# Sneaker Price Comparison model

Tags: comparison, e-commerce, price, google-reseller-api, sneakers

i would like to build a sneaker price comparison website to let my audience find the best online reseller to buy the sneaker at the specific time when they are comparing for the specific model of sneaker and size they want.

in order to do so we need to get a Programme which brings updated price by each size of sneakers/shoes from different sneaker reseller platforms for comparison at the specific time and date when user is searching for it.

I am new to programming and have no knowledge how to achieve this task